# Install services in assembly with specific namespace in a console app with castle windsor

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I have the following setup: A `console application`, and a `services project` with a range of services.

I am trying to use Windsor Castle to install specific services in the application, depending on their namespace in the application.

**I have got the following to work fine in my application**:

```
Container.Install(Castle.Windsor.Installer.Configuration.FromXmlFile("components.config"));
```

However, I have trouble getting the "register all service with specific namespace to work".

In a web application I have made previously, I got the following code to work. However, it seems that when I use Container.Register in my console application, I cannot resolve the services later on.

**Code I've previously used in a web application**:

```
// All services in service DLL
            var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(Server.MapPath("~/bin/LetterAmazer.Business.Services.dll"));
            ;
            Container.Register(
                Classes.FromAssembly(assembly)
                    .InNamespace("LetterAmazer.Business.Services.Services")
                    .WithServiceAllInterfaces());

            Container.Register(
                Classes.FromAssembly(assembly)
                    .InNamespace("LetterAmazer.Business.Services.Services.FulfillmentJobs")
                    .WithServiceAllInterfaces());

            Container.Register(
                Classes.FromAssembly(assembly)
                    .InNamespace("LetterAmazer.Business.Services.Services.PaymentMethods.Implementations")
                    .WithServiceAllInterfaces());



            // All factories in service DLL
            Container.Register(
                Classes.FromAssembly(assembly)
                    .InNamespace("LetterAmazer.Business.Services.Factory")
                    .WithServiceAllInterfaces());


            Container.Register(Component.For<LetterAmazerEntities>());
```

When I use the `Container.Register` code in my console application, I cannot do the following:

```
orderService = ServiceFactory.Get<IOrderService>();
                fulfillmentService = ServiceFactory.Get<IFulfillmentService>();
```

As I get a "service could not be resolved".

The code is run in a BackgroundService class, with the following code:

```
public void Start()
        {
            logger.Info("Starting Background Service...");
            Container.Install(Castle.Windsor.Installer.Configuration.FromXmlFile("components.config"));

            ISchedulerFactory scheduleFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            scheduler = scheduleFactory.GetScheduler();
            scheduler.Start();

            ThreadStart threadStart = new System.Threading.ThreadStart(ScheduleJobs);
            new Thread(threadStart).Start();

            logger.Info("DONE!");
        }
```

So to sum it all up: how do register all services / classes with a specific namespace, in an external DLL, in a console application?

**EDIT:**

ServiceFactory.cs:

```
public class ServiceFactory
    {
        private static ServiceFactory instance = new ServiceFactory();
        private IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();

        private ServiceFactory()
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the container.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The container.</value>
        public static IWindsorContainer Container
        {
            get { return instance.container; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets this instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static T Get<T>()
        {
            return instance.container.Resolve<T>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets all this instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IList<T> GetAll<T>()
        {
            return instance.container.ResolveAll<T>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the specified name.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="name">The name.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static T Get<T>(string name)
        {
            return (T)instance.container.Resolve<T>(name);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets all the specified name.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="name">The name.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IList<T> GetAll<T>(string name)
        {
            return instance.container.ResolveAll<T>(name);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT-2**

If I try to make a resolve in the BackgroundService, after registering the services to my container, I get a:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException' occurred in Castle.Windsor.dll

Additional information: No component for supporting the service LetterAmazer.Business.Services.Domain.Orders.IOrderService was found
```

However, I can see that in debug, the IOrderService exists in the "All services" in my container.

**EDIT-3**

```
 public interface IOrderService
    {
        Order Create(Order order);

        Order Update(Order order);
        void UpdateByLetters(IEnumerable<Letter> letters);

        List<Order> GetOrderBySpecification(OrderSpecification specification);
        Order GetOrderById(int orderId);
        Order GetOrderById(Guid orderId);

        void Delete(Order order);

        List<OrderLine> GetOrderLinesBySpecification(OrderLineSpecification specification);

        void ReplenishOrderLines(Order order);
    }
```

**EDIT-4: Order service**

Note: some of the implementation has been cut

```
public class OrderService : IOrderService
    {
        private IOrderFactory orderFactory;

        private LetterAmazerEntities repository;
        private ILetterService letterService;
        private ICustomerService customerService;

        public OrderService(LetterAmazerEntities repository,
            ILetterService letterService,
            IOrderFactory orderFactory, ICustomerService customerService)
        {
            this.repository = repository;
            this.letterService = letterService;
            this.orderFactory = orderFactory;
            this.customerService = customerService;
        }

        public Order Create(Order order)
        {
            DbOrders dborder = new DbOrders();

            foreach (var orderLine in order.OrderLines)
            {
                var dbOrderLine = setOrderline(orderLine);
                dborder.DbOrderlines.Add(dbOrderLine);
            }


            dborder.Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
            dborder.OrderCode = GenerateOrderCode();
            dborder.OrderStatus = (int)OrderStatus.Created;
            dborder.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            dborder.DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
            dborder.PaymentMethod = "";
            dborder.CustomerId = order.Customer != null ? order.Customer.Id : 0;

            Price price = new Price();
            price.PriceExVat = order.CostFromLines();
            price.VatPercentage = order.Customer.VatPercentage();
            order.Price = price;

            dborder.Total = order.Price.Total;
            dborder.VatPercentage = order.Price.VatPercentage;
            dborder.PriceExVat = order.Price.PriceExVat;

            repository.DbOrders.Add(dborder);

            repository.SaveChanges();

            return GetOrderById(dborder.Id);
        }

        public Order GetOrderById(Guid orderId)
        {
            DbOrders dborder = repository.DbOrders.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Guid == orderId);
            if (dborder == null)
            {
                throw new ItemNotFoundException("Order");
            }

            var lines = repository.DbOrderlines.Where(c => c.OrderId == dborder.Id).ToList();
            var order = orderFactory.Create(dborder, lines);

            return order;
        }

        public Order GetOrderById(int orderId)
        {
            DbOrders dborder = repository.DbOrders.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == orderId);
            if (dborder == null)
            {
                throw new ItemNotFoundException("Order");
            }

            var lines = repository.DbOrderlines.Where(c => c.OrderId == orderId).ToList();
            var order = orderFactory.Create(dborder, lines);

            return order;
        }

        public void Delete(Order order)
        {
            var dborder = repository.DbOrders.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == order.Id);
            repository.DbOrders.Remove(dborder);
            repository.SaveChanges();

        }
        public void DeleteOrder(Order order)
        {
            var dborder = repository.DbOrders.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == order.Id);

            repository.DbOrders.Remove(dborder);
            repository.SaveChanges();
        }




        #endregion


    }
```

Comment: You really need to make a SSCCE - (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions). Just making it will likely help solve your issue and make it easier for others(and me) to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do the same thing in a console application too. You just have to create the assembly instance. Considering that the assembly is in the same folder, this should work:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("MyAssembly.dll");

Container.Register(
    Classes.FromAssembly(assembly)
           .InNamespace("MyNamespace")
           .WithServiceAllInterfaces());
```

Comment: When I do this, I cannot resolve the services in my ScheduleJob class.  The servicefactory doesn't have registered the classes, and when I do the following it doesn't resolve the service. ServiceFactory.Get<IOrderService>();

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard That means at least you are correctly loading the assembly, otherwise it would throw an exception. Can you check if the IOrderService implementation is public.

Comment: Let me clearify. In the BackgroundService.cs, it loads the services perfectly, and I can see them in the ServiceFactory. However, then when going into my ScheduleJob, it is empty. 
When I use the Install call, I can call them inside the ScheduleJob.

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard When do you try to resolve them? Is it before the registration?

Comment: The flow is: backgroundservice has a method called Start(), which register all the classes (you can see the 'Start()' method).
 
Then I start a new thread with my deliveryjobs class, after registering the services

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard Maybe there is an error with Service Locator implementation (ServiceFactory class).

Comment: I just added my ServiceFactory code :-) Thanks a lot for taking your time by the way - really happy with that

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard It seems OK. Can you verify that the IOrderService can be resolved after registration in BackgroundService class?

Comment: I just tried, and got an interesting result. See edit 2:

An unhandled exception of type 'Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException' occurred in Castle.Windsor.dll

Additional information: No component for supporting the service LetterAmazer.Business.Services.Domain.Orders.IOrderService was found

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard Do you have an implementation of that interface in the assembly we loaded? If there is, is it public?

Comment: Yes. It finds all the services in "LetterAmazer.Business.Services.Services", and then takes all the interfaces with them. So instead of looking at interfaces and finding their implementations, it looks at implementations and then finds their interfaces:

 Container.Register(
                Classes.FromAssembly(assembly)
                    .InNamespace("LetterAmazer.Business.Services.Services")
                    .WithServiceAllInterfaces());

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard But it is failing to register IOrderService somehow. Can you post that class?

Comment: Sure, just added it under "Edit-3" :-)

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard What about the class that implements IOrderService interface? Is it public?

Comment: Yes, I just added that code as well :-) And this works fine in my MVC application

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard That seems fine as well. Did you also add its namespace? `LetterAmazer.Business.Services.Orders` maybe? I'm out of ideas, maybe there is a simple error we are missing.

Comment: Yes, I use resharper as well, so it should suggest it :-) 
Well, I am going to say thanks a lot for all your attempts! Insane amount of help :-) I will make a bounty when I can, and then we will see what went wrong

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard shouldn't your `IWindsorContainer` be `static` (and even `readonly`) in your `ServiceFactory`? And, BTW, Service Locator is an anti-pattern and should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: What you need is a small self contained example or a SSCCE (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions). Just making it will likely help you isolate the problem yourself and if not, it will make it a lot easier for others(and me) to help out. Btw, you're kind of butchering the approach of using windsor - but that's a side story.